# Initialize vector member with the parameters of constructor

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

Is it possible to initialize a vector member with the initialization list of the constructor. I give some incorrect codes below.

```
#ifndef _CLASSA_H_
#define _CLASSA_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class CA{
public:
    CA();
    ~CA();

private:
    std::vector<int> mCount;
    std::vector<string> mTitle;
};
```

The implementation of the constructor in .cpp file

```
// I want to do it this way
#pragma once

#include "classa.h"


// Constructor
CA::CA(int pCount, std::string pTitle) :mCount(pCount), mTitle(pTitle)
{

}


// Destructor
CA::~CA()
{

}
```

in main file

```
#include "classa.h"
int main()
{
    CA A1(25, "abcd");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialize the `vector` members with the the parameters passed to `CA::CA` as elements, you can use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11), for which the [constructor of `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) taking `std::initializer_list` will be used for initialization. e.g.

```
CA::CA(int pCount, std::string pTitle) :mCount{pCount}, mTitle{pTitle}
//                                            ~      ~        ~      ~
{
    // now mCount contains 1 element with value 25,
    //     mTitle consains 1 element with value "abcd"
}
```